# Vim-LatexSuite: /bin/bash: latex command not found

Tags: environment-variables, vim, latex, paths, texlive

***TeXLive 2015:*** I installed `TeXLive 2015` following the simplest instruction `sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu` (without any options) of [scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu@GitHub](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu).

---

***Vim-Latex-Suite:*** I installed `Vim-Latex-Suite` following these [Installation Instructions](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download), including these [recommended settings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html).

However, `\ll` (to compile .tex in Latex-Suite) does not work.
The command `:!latex -interaction=nonstopmode %` shows

```
/bin/bash: latex: command not found
shell returned 127
```

---

***My current configurations:***

`echo $PATH` in ubuntu shows:

```
/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

`:echo $PATH` in vim shows:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

`which latex` shows `/opt/texbin/latex`;
and `latex --version` shows

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.17; using libpng 1.6.17
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

***Two methods which do not work:***

1. Adding `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/texbin/` to file `.bashrc`
2. The method from [TeX Live and vim-latexsuite PATH problems](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199287) does not work for me:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/profile.d/latex.sh  
   export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux"
   ```

---

***ADDED:*** By the way, in my another Ubuntu system with latex installed in another way, `which latex` gives `/usr/bin/latex` and `vim-latex` works.

Comment: Add the output of `:echo $PATH`  (in Vim) to your post.

Comment: @muru It is `/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`; added in the post. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try logging off and on again? You obviously have the binary `/opt/texbin/latex`, you probably need to log off and after you log on again your environment will be right and vim should be able to start `latex`

Comment: @sмurf Yes, I even restarted my computer. I am rather confused. By the way, in my another computer with latex installed in another way, `which latex` gives `/usr/bin/latex` and vim-latex works.

Comment: Do you still have PATH exported after adding TeXLive to it? Because it seems it isn't exported (that's why you can see it in bash, not in a child process like Vim, unless you specially set PATH for Vim). To confirm, compare with output of `sh -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: @muru `sh -c 'echo $PATH'` gives `/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/texbin/`; is it OK?

Comment: It's OK, and surprising. It seems Vim seems to have a PATH set for it. What is the output of `type vim` and `grep PATH .vimrc .vim -R`?

Comment: @muru `type vim` outputs `vim is /usr/bin/vim`; `grep PATH .vimrc .vim -R` outputs a long result; pls see [gist@GitHub](https://gist.github.com/hengxin/dca42a828959e1a4b112).

Comment: @hengxin you were running Vim with sudo all this time?

Comment: @muru Sorry for that (I have just deleted (*accidentally*) an important directory with `sudo` today)... Great thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script `sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu` will install latex at `/opt/texbin`, where is not a default path(`/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux`) for latex.

It seems you have installed two `latex`, any one of them should work in case you set their corresponding `$PATH` in `.bashrc`.

I note that your shell and vim have different `$PATH`. Vim cannot find `latex` with it’s `$PATH`. 
It is not likely that you started vim in an old shell as you restarted your computer. 
I guess you run vim with `sudo`, as `sudo` uses root's environment, where usually keeps a default `$PATH`, exactly the same value in your vim.

Comment: Exporting `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux` and then running vim (for .tex) without `sudo` works!